# Scaling to different resolutions in C# with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resolution, scaling

I am creating a windows form application in Visual Studio Community 2015. I've built the interface on a 1080p monitor and anchored controls so that when the form is resized, things stay where I want and stretch how I want.

The problem is, I need to try and get this to work on a monitor that is 1024 x 768 and the minimum size of my application is actually larger than that. This causes controls to overlap due to the anchoring and some controls aren't shown at all (they are cut off).

Is there anyway I can easily scale my application to different resolutions automatically?

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms

Comment: It is extremely painful to setup in Windows Forms, is there a reason why you can't use WPF?

Comment: I've honestly just never used WPF before. Is there much of a difference? Excuse the ignorance, I'm pretty new.

Comment: That's fine it's all part of the learning experience. WPF is a vastly different technology from the ground up, it is much newer much more powerful and is designed to scale on it's own. If you haven't invested too much time in Windows Forms I would dump it and move to WPF. Visual Studio has great support for it as well so no problem there and you can also utilize the skills learned from it in Windows 10 Universal Apps.

Comment: Interesting, I'll be sure to have a look at it for my next project. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Pretty sure there are good resources on Google for scaling Windows Forms in the meantime

Comment: Set the form's MinimumSize property so no overlap occurs.  And set the AutoScroll property to True.  That makes the app usable, no more than that.  Reducing the form's Font.Size property is another very quick way.  And no, there is no magic cure for cramming too many piggies into a too small a poke, not in WPF either.